# OpenGL ES 2.0 Matrix stack replacement

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, matrix

I know this has already been covered a great deal, but I promise this one is different. I am making an app that must support OpenGL ES 1.1 as well as OpenGL ES 2.0, and I want to know if there is a way of implementing a custom matrix stack in *OpenGL ES 1.1* that also works with 2.0. If not, is it efficient to create a separate context or something and grab the matrix data from that and putting it into an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader? My main goals here are to be able to write a single function for everything, not one version of each function for each version of OpenGL ES.

I am solving this to some extent by writing a sort of wrapper for OpenGL ES that calls the appropriate things for the OpenGL ES version, but I am noticing that the OpenGL ES 2.0 matrix class (CC3GLMatrix, as used [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)) is much slower than the traditional OpenGL ES 1.1 matrix stack, so I want to find a more efficient way of doing it, or simply use the old matrix stack. Any ideas/suggestions?